# Codeigniter always only returning 1st row of the query result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Update**

I tried to use `sizeof($result)` on my `controller`and the result is more than 1, so i think ***the mistake is somewhere on the controller***.

I tried to run this query :

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `hospital` WHERE name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR address LIKE '%$keyword%' OR telp LIKE '%$keyword%'";
```

the `$keyword` depends of what user type in the app.

This is the CI query :

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from($table)
        ->like('name', $keyword, 'both')
        ->or_like('address', $keyword, 'both')
        ->or_like('telp', $keyword, 'both')
        ->get()
        ->result_array();
```

The query above always only return the 1st row.

This is in the controller :

```
if(sizeof($result) > 0)
        {
            foreach($result as $hospital)
            {
                if($hospital)
                {
                    $this->response(array('result' => 'true', 
                    'id' => $hospital['id'], 
                    'name' => $hospital['name'], 
                    'address' => $hospital['address'], 
                    'telp' => $hospital['telp']), 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->response(array('result' => 'false'), 404);
        }
```

Where is my mistake? When i tried to hard type the query in the `phpmyadmin`, the query run perfectly (returning all row).

Thanks for your time

Comment: Try outputting `$result` value with `var_dump($result)` and see what it says.

Comment: @WojciechFrącz Sorry for the long reply, it said "Unexpected token a"...i dont understand what it means. Please kindly help me

Comment: seperate the get function in your chaining code  and try to use this code $query = $this->db->get(); //newline return $query->result_array();

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your query result to a `$query` variable and then you are trying to iterate over `$result` array that has not been declared anywhere. Try:

```
if(sizeof($query) > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

or change the `$query` to `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another way to handle this requirement.

```
$this->db->select('*')
        ->from($table)
        ->like('name', $keyword, 'both')
        ->or_like('address', $keyword, 'both')
        ->or_like('telp', $keyword, 'both');

$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
  $result= $query->result_array();
  //and bla bla
}
```

By using

```
$query->num_rows()
```

we can return also total number of rows from model.
You can also made chack in model class if num_rows is zero return false and check from controller if function return array or false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need ->result_array();

->get() is good enough.

Remove all ->result_array() instances.